# How to set default value from mysql join interval yearmonth

Tags: mysql, date, mariadb, left-join, cross-join

I have problem with my query. I have two tables and I want join them to get the results based on primary key on first table, but I missing 1 data from first table.

[this my fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ef0083/4)

as you can see, I missing "xx3" from month 1

[image]

I have tried to change left and right join but, the results stil same.
So as you can see I have to set `coalesce(sum(b.sd_qty),0) as total,` if no `qty`, set `0` as default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should cross join the table to the distinct dates also:

```
SELECT a.item_code,
       COALESCE(SUM(b.sd_qty), 0) total,
       DATE_FORMAT(d.sd_date, '%m-%Y') month_year
FROM item a 
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT sd_date 
  FROM sales_details 
  WHERE sd_date >= '2020-04-01' - INTERVAL 3 MONTH AND sd_date < '2020-05-01'
) d 
LEFT JOIN sales_details b 
ON a.item_code = b.item_code AND b.sd_date = d.sd_date
GROUP BY month_year, a.item_code
ORDER BY month_year, a.item_code;
```

Or, for MySql 8.0+, with a recursive CTE that returns the starting dates of all the months that you want the results, which can be cross joined to the table:

```
WITH RECURSIVE dates AS (
  SELECT '2020-04-01' - INTERVAL 3 MONTH AS sd_date
  UNION ALL
  SELECT sd_date + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
  FROM dates 
  WHERE sd_date + INTERVAL 1 MONTH < '2020-05-01'
)
SELECT a.item_code,
       COALESCE(SUM(b.sd_qty), 0) total,
       DATE_FORMAT(d.sd_date, '%m-%Y') month_year
FROM item a CROSS JOIN dates d 
LEFT JOIN sales_details b 
ON a.item_code = b.item_code AND DATE_FORMAT(b.sd_date, '%m-%Y') = DATE_FORMAT(d.sd_date, '%m-%Y')
GROUP BY month_year, a.item_code
ORDER BY month_year, a.item_code;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7bcfd8e12979a92f24a87549ccd799b7).

Comment: wow, your answer works great, if no one else answers I will mark this answer. So it's my fault that I didn't use cross join?

Comment: @AdityaDees you want in the results all the combinations of item_code  and yearmonth, even if there now rows for a yearmonth for certain item_codes. This is the cartesian product of the 2 datasets and can be achieved with a cross join.

Comment: @AdityaDees what is your MySql version?

Comment: Ok thanks for your explanation, I'll take note of it. I am using xampp 7.4, and in my phpmyadmin my version is `Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 7.4.10`

Comment: @AdityaDees this is not the version of MySql. You can get the version if you execute `select version();`. If it is 8.0+ I posted a better solution.

Comment: this my version 10.4.14-MariaDB

Comment: @AdityaDees fine, you can use the 2nd query with the recursive cte: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=96e5c90ee44f9ee9eda065271281beb2